# Divs are not aligining

Tags: html, css

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but as soon as I put the item title and the sub content, the first div goes down. instead of staying in the white box.

```
<div style="width:49%; height:100px; background-color:white;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width:100px; height:100%; background-color:red;">date and time</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; height:100%; background-color:blue;">
        <div style="font-size:xx-large;">item title</div>
        <p> item sub content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

check the screenshot:
[scrshot](http://postimg.org/image/k406jalz1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `div`s like this:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46v469mb/)

#### HTML:

```
<div style="width:49%; height:100px; background-color:white;">
    <div style="vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; width:100px; height:100%; background-color:red;">date and time</div>
    <div style="vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; height:100%; background-color:blue;">
        <div style="font-size:xx-large;">item title</div>
        <p> item sub content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Glen This needs to be done since the default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline`.  So the `inline-block` `div`s will, by default, share the same lowest baseline of text, which is what you screenshot is showing.

Answer (score 0):

By floating you can prevent divs from changing their positions

```html
<div style="width:49%; height:100px; background-color:white;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width:100px; height:100%; background-color:red; float: left;">date and time</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; height:100%; background-color:blue;">
        <div style="font-size:xx-large;">item title</div>
        <p> item sub content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```